# 'user_register' hook - need to distinguish if created from wp admin panel

Tags: hooks, user-registration

Users are created in two ways in my application.

The registration form uses a gravity form hook to register the user and send to various api's.

But when creating a user from the admin panel, we use the '`user_register`' hook.

This causes a conflict because in the gravity form procedure , when calling `wp_insert_user()`, it triggers the '`user_register`' hook , interrupting the script which isn't finished saving the user to the api's.

So I would have liked a hook which is only triggered when run from the admin panel.
Can this be accomplished?

Comment: It seems like you've got this backwards, and would be better off checking if the registration was coming from the Gravity Form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `user_register` hook, then check if the user registration is happening from an admin interface with `is_admin()`:

> #### is_admin()
>
> Determines whether the current request is for an administrative interface page.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_admin/

Comment: That worked nicely, thanks!